# Determining the relative importance of Likert items

Tags: regression, feature-selection, importance

Simplified, I have 17 items that are barriers to helping. Each item is rated on a 5-point Likert scale. I have four outcomes that are different types of helping (3 binary outcomes, 1 continuous). I want to determine the relative importance of these barriers in explaining each of these helping behaviors. I would prefer to compare the barrier items themselves and not factor analyze the items. I have been reading about different variable selection and importance methods ([here](http://r-statistics.co/Variable-Selection-and-Importance-With-R.html), [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-most-important-variables-r-amit-jain), or [here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/machine-learning/feature-selection/)).

I am learning toward a relative importance method (relaimpo/relimp) or one using a random forest method (randomForest, Boruta). Are either of these (or any other variable selection or importance methods) better/more robust given I have 5 point Likert items as predictors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either is more or less relevant or robust for five-point Likert-type scales.  The key consideration is more focused on whether any model selection has occurred.

Overall, the two methods are fairly different in terms of how they approach importance but *can* result in similar results as is discussed by Groemping [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.08199).

The Shapley/Dominance/LMG method as discussed by Groemping assumes model selection has been completed.  Thus, LMG method assumes the helping behaviors used as features/predictors *are* valid predictors and will assign non-zero importance to all features.

The PMVD and RF methods discussed by Groemping do not assume such selection has taken place and will assign zero importance to truly non-relevant features.  This latter approach might fit your case better as it sounds like no other modeling has been completed based on your description.

Reference:

Grömping, U. (2009). Variable importance assessment in regression: linear regression versus random forest. *The American Statistician, 63(4)*, 308-319.

Comment: Thank you for the link and information. I agree after reading the RF methods seem the most appropriate, with conditional permutation importance given that my predictors are highly correlated in some cases.